# Cannot create IsAccessible statement for User object

Tags: soql, security, user, sobjecttype

I'm trying to create this statement:

```
if(User.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
        User userData=[SELECT id, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE id=:user.id];
        return userData.Profile.Name;
}
```

But I cannot do it. I get this error when I try to deploy:

*Variable does not exist: sObjectType*

How can I check User object accessibility then?

Comment: Any chance you have a class named User? Given code compiles in my orgs so far. Can you also check if there if posted snipped is same as one being deployed?

Comment: Or a variable/class member that is masking the type. What happens if you try `if (Schema.User.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()) {`?

Comment: @PhilW actually you are correct, this is the minimal reproducible snippet

`Account user = new Account();
System.debug(User.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible());`

Comment: @PhilW that statement works, but I don't know if it's correct. Why can I put ```Case.SobjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()```, but I cannot do it with User?

Comment: See the earlier comments; you probably have a class, class member or variable called "User" or "user" that is masking the `User` object and confusing the Apex compiler. By adding the `Schema` prefix you are simply helping Apex select the correct type.

Comment: @PhilW Yeah, it was the problem. I had a variable in method params called 'user'. I changed it and it works. Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that it conflicts with some variable or class with the same name as User. To avoid this problem you could run this code, which uses `Schema` class:

```
if(Schema.User.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
    User userData=[SELECT id, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
    System.debug(userData.Profile.Name);
}
```